# ThinkPad T450s Wireless interface not detected when installing Ubuntu 16.04 mini.iso

Tags: networking, system-installation, iso, thinkpad

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Mate minimal installation using the Ubuntu 16.04 mini.iso on my ThinkPad T450s. I was able to do so on my T60, but I'm running into network config issues on this machine. For some reason, the installer is not detecting the Intel wireless card, despite the fact that the correct drivers seem to be included in the mini.iso package (iwlwifi-7265, if I'm not mistaken). It detects the ethernet interface and tries to configure that, but of course fails because it's not connected. I tried disabling ethernet in the bios to "force" it to configure the wireless network, but then the installer just says, "No network interfaces detected."

I'll add that the wireless works fine with the currently installed OS, which is vanilla Ubuntu 16.04, so I can't understand why it wouldn't work with the 16.04 mini.iso.

EDIT: Outputs removed

Comment: Let's start by identifying the device. Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` If it is indeed an Intel 7265, or similar, please add: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 edited with the results you requested

Comment: Looks great so far, although we will probably install even newer firmware. Please add: `rfkill list all` and also:`iwconfig`

Comment: @chili555 added

Comment: Looks like you are connected to *attwifi*. Did we fix it?

Comment: LOL no, as I said in my original post, the wifi works fine on the currently installed OS (Ubuntu16.04). But I want to replace the current OS with Ubuntu Mate minimal installation using the Ubuntu 16.04 mini.iso, and that's where the trouble starts. The installer doesn't detect the wireless interface, the very one that's working correctly right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41780/discussion-between-chili555-and-alcuin-arundel).

Comment: I had this same problem with the server edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Intel 7265 uses the driver *iwlwifi* which also requires the module *iwlmvm*. The mini.iso evidently provides drivers for a limited number of common networking devices.

I downloaded and extracted the mini.iso and, unfortunately, the module *iwlmvm* is not included. As well, when you tried to install, you got a message:

> "failed to load module iwlmvm (error 256), is dynamic loading
>   enabled?"

I know of no way, aside from a temporary ethernet connection, to get a working network interface with your Lenovo T450s.

Answer (score 1):

I recently picked up a T450s to replace my T430 that took a trample and had a bent frame.

I ran into this very issue while trying to do a minimal install on the T450s. Thanks to the answer by chili555, I was able to track down a solution which would let me perform the install wirelessly from a thumb drive.

Since the `iwlmvm` kernel module is needed for this wireless card, where does this file come from anyway?

```
root@canti:/lib/modules# find /lib/modules -name "iwlmvm.ko"
/lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
root@canti:/lib/modules# apt-file search /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
```

This module is provided by the linux-image-extra package. The mini.iso installer (as well as the Ubuntu Server ISO) doesn't seem to have this package installed for the live OS.

Once the installer fails to connect, hit 'Go Back' and select the menu option to open a shell. Check the version of the running kernel.
In my case, this was `4.4.0-21-generic`.

Searching for this in Ubuntu Package Search, you are able to find where you can download the `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic` package:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kernel/linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic

Downloading `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic_4.4.0-21.37_amd64.deb` to another machine (or the same one if you are planning to reinstall), extract the file:

```
canti:~/Downloads/linux-extra$ ls
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic_4.4.0-21.37_amd64.deb                                           canti:~/Downloads/linux-extra$ ar xv linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic_4.4.0-21.37_amd64.deb
x - debian-binary
x - control.tar.gz
x - data.tar.bz2
canti:~/Downloads/linux-extra$ tar xfvj data.tar.bz2

canti:~/Downloads/linux-extra$ find . -name "iwlmvm.ko"
./lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
canti:~/Downloads/linux-extra$
```

By copying this module to a thumb drive, you can copy it somewhere on the root filesystem of the installer (which is running in memory) and insert it manually.

```
~ # insmod iwlmvm.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module iwlmvm.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

What's this? Checking dmesg, it looks like this module relies on symbols from another module.

If you check the output of lsmod on another machine, you can determine the other modules needed to load:

```
$ lsmod | grep iwlmvm
iwlmvm                311296  0
mac80211              737280  2 iwldvm,iwlmvm
iwlwifi               200704  2 iwldvm,iwlmvm
cfg80211              565248  4 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm,iwlmvm
```

In my case, `cfg80211` was already loaded on `mini.iso`, so all I needed to load were the following two modules (copying `mac80211.ko` in the same method as `iwlmvm.ko`):

```
~ # insmod mac80211.ko
~ # insmod iwlmvm.ko
```

At this stage, if you check dmesg again, you will see that iwlwifi has detected your wireless card. You can exit the shell and try to detect network hardware again, and you'll be able to complete the installation with your wireless card.

Hope this helps!